# I cannot write numbers in the screen! (assembly code)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have a program to add two numbers but whenever I run it and try to input a number it doesn't work. Only characters shows up in the screen!

### Here is the code:

```
.model small

.data
message db "Enter a number you want to add $"
message2 db " Enter another number $"
message3 db " + $"
Message4 db " = $"

.code
main proc

mov ax, seg message
mov ds, ax
mov dx, offset message
mov ah, 9h
int 21h

mov ah, 1h
int 21h
mov bl, al

mov ax, seg message2
mov ds, ax
mov dx, offset message2
mov ah, 9h
int 21h

mov ah, 1h
int 21h
mov cl, al

mov dl, bl

mov ah, 2h
int 21h

mov ax, seg message3
mov ds, ax
mov dx, offset message3
mov ah, 9h
int 21h

mov dl, cl

mov ah, 2h
int 21h

mov ax, seg message4
mov ds, ax
mov dx, offset message4
mov ah, 9h
int 21h

sub bl, 30h
sub cl, 30h
add bl, cl

mov dl, bl
add dl, 30h

mov ah, 2h
int 21h

endp

end main
```

---

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code, please. We can't troubleshoot something we can't see.

Comment: If the value of the result is greater than 9, then we have to split the value for a decimal output in more then one ASCII by dividing the result before converting every part of the value to ASCII. Example if the result is 10, the we have to print two ASCIIs, the 1 and the 0.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the code, itis working well. The problem is that I cannot input numbers to the program. For example, if I press 1 the character & shows instead in the screen :)

Comment: I see that we have to input two seperate ASCIIs numbers and after that, the numbers will be add together and the result will be output to the screen. I see only one problem if one of the input value, or if the result of the calculation is above the number of 9. But i do not understand why this code do not let you input a value for a calculation, if the inputs and the result for adding is lower than 9. In other words, if you input a "1" and for the next input another "1", then the result and the last output have to be "2".

Answer (score -1):

The program presented will work correctly (enough) if each inputted character is indeed a digit!
Even so the sum should not exceed 9 to display correct results.
The fact that the OP shymaa states that when he/she pushes '1' he/she obtains '&' might indicate he/she is using a keyboard with a Belgian or French layout. Both these characters appear on the same keycap.
So perhaps the use of SHIFT or CAPSLOCK is in order. Or use the numerical keypad if available!